# Suggestions for making this deleted question conform to the rules/guidelines of this site

Tags: discussion, specific-question, post-ban, question-quality, quality-improvement

I am currently question banned, and after talking to several people it seems that mods are suggesting I try to make this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57531632/direction-on-creating-a-workflow-driven-app-for-an-hoa-home-owners-association) follow the SO guidelines/rules.

I have two other questions that are similar but the earlier ones don't contain as much detail, so I deleted them and started over. Because I didn't know the site rules.

> tldr: Is there a workflow engine or a means for dealing with a request
>   status/tracking history, without throwing a lot of custom code at the
>   problem?
>
> In order to provide some background about what I've thought so far, on
>   the db side, I could create a Requests table to house requests. Create
>   another Statuses table to provide a lookup for status (Approved,
>   Denied, etc.). Create another table to hold ConversationHistory.
>   Another to hold Attachments/images and point to a file directory (most
>   likely as opposed to storing attachment as base 64 encoded in the db).
>   That's high level. On the C# side, create REST API services to create,
>   read, update, delete requests. We'd also need a db table for request
>   type (e.g., shed, siding change, siding color change,
>   architectural/addition, etc. per the request form below).
>
> On the front end, we'd need a dashboard to show requests that need
>   your attention - once a request has been submitted, it needs to be
>   reviewed by ACC members for example. There'd be some
>   indicator/chart/widget to show requests that have been approved,
>   denied, approved with conditions, or those with questions, with links
>   to each. The main need for the dashboard would be to notify users that
>   they need to perform some action. The site would track history most
>   especially and allow the users to see what's been done at a glance
>   without wading through countless emails.
>
> The Angular pages would be simple forms I think - to allow the
>   homeowner/requestor to enter details like name, address, request type,
>   add attachments/images. The ACC members would just be able to add
>   comments to the request and choose a status, like approved, etc. I
>   would think the site would need to keep a log of activity, so that
>   would necessitate another db table for ActivityLog or something like
>   that. REST service calls would be made as needed in a transaction to
>   ensure everything passed/failed. Update pages would be role-based to
>   allow only the original requestor to make changes to certain fields
>   like the attachments, or description of the request. A comment section
>   for the ACC members would probably not be in an update page but more
>   like a view page with the ability add to a running log of what's going
>   on with the request. I'd visualize the ability to delete/update the
>   comments only by the user making the addition. Of course, only ACC
>   members could update the status. The homeowner would of course also be
>   allowed to delete their request. Email notifications would need to
>   occur on request change.
>
> This sounds like a tool like Gemini that I've used in the past, I
>   believe an open source issue tracker. Or maybe like a Jira tool. But
>   specifically for ACC changes. Basically, this site would allow a
>   homeowner as well as ACC members and the property management company
>   to track these requests like we've never been able to do previously.
>   Does that provide adequate details and background? This seems like a
>   lot of custom code and a lot of work, and the question is whether this
>   seems reasonable, or is there an easier way?
>
> I just came up with another process improvement as I'm thinking about
>   this more. Instead of having to manually go to surrounding neighbor's
>   homes, the site would notify adjacent neighbors via email/text (based
>   on their site notification preferences) for required signatures.
>   They'd click the site request link in their text/email for them to
>   electronically sign let's say. That'd clean up the process even more
>   and reduce legwork and actually being able to actually track down
>   neighbors that aren't at home or on vacation or difficult to locate.
>   This would eliminate the (um, ridiculous!) need to send out certified
>   mail to a neighbor you can't contact or one who refuses to sign the
>   notification form.
>
> The domain context:
>
> I've researched creating a free web app for our local HOA ACC
>   (Architectural Control Committee) changes for over two hours and was
>   looking for some direction. Standard C#/SQL Server on the backend with
>   Angular 8 on the front end. I think I'm looking for a workflow type of
>   engine to accomplish what this app needs to do, but not sure it
>   exists. I'm familiar with Microsoft's workflows like Windows Workflow
>   Foundation, SharePoint workflows and most recently, Durable Functions
>   in Azure. WF looks dated and difficult to learn, especially for an
>   off-the-clock freebie app. SharePoint is definitely out based on the
>   environment and Durable Functions Azure functions seem to be possibly
>   an option for creating microservice workflows. I'm not sure if they're
>   indefinitely totally free for low volume on a month to month basis as
>   long as it's less than 1,000,000 executions and 400,000 GB/s due to
>   the free grant. That might help if we could use Durable Functions to
>   manage a simple workflow with serverless functions that are very
>   granular and focused on using maybe a queue and table storage. Any
>   feedback there would be appreciated. I'm new to Azure functions.
>
> I'm not looking for a property management software like Yardi, or an
>   HOA software system. I'm looking specifically for something that
>   allows us to manage homeowner changes per the page here. The only
>   thing I found that's close to what I'm looking for is here, and it
>   seems to be for properties in Texas. I'm not sure if it's a custom
>   solution or an off the shelf package, but it looks like it supports at
>   least the functionality I'm needing at a high level.
>
> We currently have a very painful manual request system in place.
>   Homeowner has a change like building a deck, changing their siding or
>   replacing a roof and the HOA covenants require them to email the
>   change after filling out the aforementioned form. The ACC committee
>   reviews the submission, physically meets to discuss the changes, then
>   approves, approves with conditions or denies the request. If it gets
>   denied or has an administrative denial pending updates, it goes back
>   to the homeowner for updates. They can then make the required updates
>   to the request and run it back up the flagpole by emailing it to the
>   ACC again and the ACC approves/denies once again. Rinse and repeat. If
>   it's approved the homeowner is notified this is the case and they can
>   proceed with their changes. The current process is painful and in an
>   email thread rather than being in some sort of issue tracker that
>   records conversation threads, details and updates. The ACC also misses
>   emails, and they miss request details a lot. It would be nice if we
>   could manage this process better. That's where I think some sort of
>   workflow engine could be very helpful. There seems to be a lot of HOA
>   software out there but haven't found one to manage this process. I'm
>   not sure if it would just require a state-based database entry and
>   simplify the request down to states like submitted, approved, approved
>   with conditions, denied or request additional information. And lots of
>   custom code. The thing is, it would need to email the parties to
>   notify them of actions that have occurred with the request and to
>   check the site to provide more updates. I would think it should have a
>   dashboard to provide a way to see the user action items and maybe
>   graphical eye candy to reflect needs, accomplishments, waiting on
>   somebody else or something like that. Any ideas would be appreciated.
>   I'm just getting thoughts in mind on how best to proceed. Thanks in
>   advance...

I feel like this question is so far removed from the rules, and it's no longer applicable I'm not sure why you're kind of forcing me to undelete it.

I no longer intend to work on this project, so the question is now irrelevant, so I'd prefer you just remove it and the other two before it.

I think it was Rene who suggested it might be a good fit for the Software Engineering site, but looking for suggestions in how to best proceed.

Comment: Per the comment *on that question*, there's really nothing you can do to make it on topic; it's far too broad.

Comment: Yeah, exactly Jon, that's why I say I'm not sure there's much I can do with it. That's why I'm asking for suggestions. I've undeleted the question, but it remains in a closed status.

Comment: Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be anything you can do to it to make it fit the guidelines.  About the only thing you can likely do is request disassociation from it; might be enough to get you out of the question ban.  Gotta use that sparingly, though; it's not meant to be a get out of jail free card.

Comment: Okay, that's what I'm asking for then. It's too far out in left field to salvage IMO. Moderators - please disassociate me from that question. Or - if someone suggests this - I could just completely remove basically everything in that question and ask something simple or another question entirely.

Comment: Best idea is to flag the question as other, and request it that way.  Just keep in mind that it's not a guarantee, and is done at the CM's discretion.

Comment: ^^ Adding to that: do mention you brought it to meta and the flag was the suggested approach, and that you're open to discussing it further with the moderators on this post, if they feel it necessary.

Comment: This question is very likely not the only deleted question you have. Why not improve the others?

Comment: RIght. `I have two other questions that are similar but the earlier ones don't contain as much detail` as stated in the OP. They're similar but the reason I deleted them was because I thought I'd just start over and make a flailing and really bad attempt to conform but because I hadn't read the rules, it didn't matter.

Comment: I think it's kinda funny - and awesome - that I've received several upvotes on old questions, even ones five years old. That says to me that people care and are trying to help me. And I get a super warm fuzzy about that. Feelin' the love today... :)

Comment: And yep, @BDL, Jon Ericson suggested I edit/improve the others so I think I'll try and do that. I guess I can just pretty much delete all that content and ask just one thing that I'd like to know.

Answer (score 6):

Now this answer is as much for future readers of this site as it is for you. So bear this in mind.

No one is forcing you to undelete that or in actual fact to do anything except to not circumvent the site's rules.

I sent you a message and gave you the only guidance I have for the site. I made it clear the mods cannot lift post bans. I'm not sure the community team can. I have made no reference to improving any particular post. If a post is hopelessly off topic, there's not much you can do to make it work on the site.

The only advice I have is to improve your post score generally and not to create new accounts to circumvent the post ban.

People are encouraged to work on post quality before getting into a ban. I also suggested that you can contact the community team if needed. I'm not sure what else you're expecting of the mods when we actually have no power to change this.

Please do not present a situation in a light that is truly not accurate. Pardon my frustration, but I'm tired of moderation actions being misinterpreted or worse twisted publicly into something that they are not. We are not wizards and we are also not tyrants. We have some power, but are limited by the site. All we can do is to uphold the site's policies. It continues to disappoint me when I put out a hand in good faith and find it here on meta somehow contorted, so it appears to be an unreasonable demand.

At some point there needs to be some level of user self responsibility. We strive to make the standards of what we expect when posting known. It's well documented in the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq). Beyond this, there needs to be a level of ability to learn how to use the site. Programming is not necessarily a simple thing to learn and master. Learning to navigate a question and answer site, is not dissimilar to learning to search and navigate the docs for programming languages and frameworks. At some point people need to ask themselves, maybe I need to do some research before posting.

I have been post limited in the early days, down voted, had posts closed. I used this to try and learn what the site didn't want and develop my posts to be of a quality the site did want.

Comment: @storyteller thanks, yes a good edit. As I tend to write for the silent majority. there's a lot of people who browse our posts and never vote or comment. so when I write, I tend to include this broader group in with the OP

Comment: Thanks Yvette. Very helpful. I reread the suggestions from @jonericson on my meta rant post from last week and he suggested editing all three of my deleted questions. I'll try to get to the rules sometime but I'm way busy. It's probably obvious but I absolutely do not like the heavy handed approach on the site. It really really makes me wanna go away. It's definitely a love-hate relationship, kind of like the one I have with facebook - you know because your friends and family are there and so if you wanna see em, you have to have a facebook account. Yeah, like that. :)

Comment: `No one is forcing you to undelete that` - what I meant was that if I don't undelete those questions, I can't ask any more questions because I'm question banned. You'd think the site would just let you delete them and so no more problem - I'm in compliance with the site rules, but nope. The site is forcing me to undelete and fix them if I wanna still play here. And by the way, that busy reference - you know where I implied I have no time - SO is forcing me to learn the rules here too. I can't even count the number of hours I've devoted recently to trying to understand the site/users/mods. Ouch

Comment: Okay, so I need to ask this I think. When I talk about being forced to do something that's my impression. Seriously. That's what I'm thinking about when I'm asked to do something in order to comply with the site rules. But as I was thinking about it, maybe I'm wrong since you state that no one is forcing me to do anything. But I feel forced, but then again, everything I assumed on this site has been wrong, so I'm wondering if I'm in the matrix, or maybe the twilight zone, so something that seems obvious to me, is in fact totally not true. Or is it? I don't even know anymore... :)

Comment: @sfors if it's any consolation I have a love hate relationship with the site too! it's encounters like these that make it worthwhile. Don't give up. It's something that we can work through. Clearly there needs to be a way for people to get out of post bans more easily - caveat - in the right circumstances. the issue is when people just don't care and take advantage of good will. If that makes sense. The problem with deleting the posts, it doesn't remove them from the ban algorithm. So it's really hard copied. I'll have a look at your posts.

Comment: @sfors I don't think you have a post ban any more.

Comment: Yep, you're right - good to go! Thanks for all the help! So, now what do I do with those deleted questions? Leave them deleted and in the current state? They really don't fit the site and so I'd have to just force three questions since there's not really anything coding-wise I need to ask from the design side.

Comment: @sfors as long as your new questions are ok - you should be fine. Leave them deleted.